# Why is PassthroughSubject completing with .finished?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm exploring Combine, and this issue has come up and perplexed me no end. My understanding is that a PassthroughSubject will exist as long as the object it is scoped in if a reference to it is stored as `AnyCancellable`.

In this example of a `loginPublisher: PassthroughSubject<User, Error>` waiting for updates to the `User` object, the `Subject.Completion.finished` block is called immediately after the first value is received.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let appState = AppState()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

@main
struct SPMDepsTestApp: SwiftUI.App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView().environmentObject(appDelegate.appState)
        }
    }
}

struct User {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

class App {
    var currentUser: User? = nil

    func login (user: User) -> Future<User, Error> {
        Future { promise in
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
                self.currentUser = user
                promise(.success(user))
            }
        }
    }
}

class AppState: ObservableObject {
    var app = App()
    var loginPublisher = PassthroughSubject<User, Error>()

    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init () {

        loginPublisher
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                    switch completion {
                        case .failure(let err):
                            dump(err)
                        case .finished:
                            print("ISSUE: loginPublisher is finished") // << Why should this happen immediately?
                    }
                }, receiveValue: { user in
                    dump(user)
                })
                .store(in: &cancellables)

        if let user = app.currentUser {
            loginPublisher.send(user)
        } else {
            app.login(user: User(id: 0, name: "AAA"))
                    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                    .subscribe(loginPublisher)
                    .store(in: &cancellables)
        }
    }
}
```

Differently, If I initialize the App object like so

```
var App = App(user: user)
```

so that `app.currentUser != nil` then the line

```
 if let user = app.currentUser {
      loginPublisher.send(user) // << loginPublisher completion (finished) block is never called
 }
```

Why is `PassthroughSubject` completing if (seemingly) loginPublisher.send() is not called synchronously?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PassthroughSubject` completes if it is subscribed to a publisher that completes.

Here's a self-contained example:

```
import Combine

let subject = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
let ticket = subject.sink(
    receiveCompletion: { print("completion: \($0)") },
    receiveValue: { print("value: \($0)") })

let t2 = Just(123)
    .subscribe(subject)
```

Output:

```
value: 123
completion: finished
```

One way to prevent the completion is to append a publisher that never completes, like this:

```
let t2 = Just(123)
    .append(Empty(completeImmediately: false))
    .subscribe(subject)
```

So in your code, it would look like this:

```
            app.login(user: User(id: 0, name: "AAA"))
                    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                    .append(Empty(completeImmediately: false))
                    .subscribe(loginPublisher)
                    .store(in: &cancellables)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've re-checked the docs and all I can see that may _insinuate_ the missing link ("A PassthroughSubject completes if it is subscribed to a publisher that completes" in my case, Future) reads as: "A PassthroughSubject drops values if there are no subscribers, or its current demand is zero." Other than that I'm not sure where I can find this info. Thanks again! Would be curious what other strategies one might employ to accomplish same.